# Is it possible to see HTTP POST data from requests in Packetbeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, packetbeat

I want to build a dashboard that is based on POST requests containing JSON data that is being sent as part of the request payload.

I added `send_request` to the Packetbeat configuration but I don't see the data in the index.

Is that possible and how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also specify the content types of the requests that you wish to include the body for via the [`include_body_for`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/1.2/configuration-protocols.html#_include_body_for) config setting. For example:

```
protocols:
  http:
    ports: [80, 8080]
    send_request: true
    include_body_for: ['application/json', 'application/javascript']
```